# Listbox in C# has an empty line when an item is added?

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, string

So, I had to use a Listbox for a small C# project, and ran into a problem. The Listbox displays file-names, and an item is added every-time someone uses a File Dialog box to add in the item. The problem is when the very first file is added, nothing shows up. but when a second file is added, its an empty line.

Here is a picture to illustrate the problem:

[image: The problem with the listbox]

Now, how do I get rid of the first blank line and properly add in the filename to the top of the listbox?

Here is the code that I am using to add to the listbox.

```
// Set a global variable to hold all the selected files result
List<String> fullFileName;

private void addBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = fileDialog.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
       // put the selected result in the global variables
       fullFileName = new List<String>(fileDialog.FileNames);
       // add just the names to the listbox
       foreach (string fileName in fullFileName)
       {
           dllBox.Items.Add(fileName.Substring(fileName.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1));
       }
   }
}
```

And here is the properties for fileDialog:

[image: FileDialog]

As well as the dllBox properties

[image: 1a1s] [image: 21]

Comment: And how would this aid me? I need to get rid of the empty listbox line.

Comment: Your code is working fine when I use it. This is WinForms, I assume?

Comment: Could you provide us with the Properties you've set on ddlBox and fileDialog?

Comment: @jaypeagi, yes this is Winforms, I will edit the properties.

Comment: Maybe there is one empty line in the control initially, by mistake. Try to clear it before you add the first item.

Comment: Can you select the "empty item"? Add more than 1 item.. what does it look like? You've tampered with a few properties that i bet you don't even know what they do. I've never had this issue to say the least..

Comment: no, I cannot select it, and more then 1 item still has same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your DrawMode to **Normal** rather than **OwnerDrawFixed** in the listbox properties.

Comment: Thanks, but that did nothing.

Comment: Strange. I am using your original code provided and it works fine for me. I set all my properties to the ones you posted and this was the only one that caused items to be added incorrectly.

Comment: Very well, I'll try this on another computer and see what happens.

Comment: thank you, it turns out it worked. I reset the control and changed the setting again, resulting in it working. Thank you! Accepted!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and see what happens.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var dialog = new OpenFileDialog())
    {
        dialog.Multiselect = true;
        if (dialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            listbox.Items.Clear();
            listbox.Items.AddRange(dialog.FileNames.Select(x => System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)).ToArray());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Silkut I added in the clear intentionally in case there is already an emtpy item in the list before the Items.AddRange. If the OP doesn't want to clear the list each time, it is easy to remove it himselve.

Answer (score 0):

Unclear. Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. There are also some strange things in your code (`string file = ...` never used, `fullFileName` that get a new instance each time, no idea where `fileDialog` is instantiated...).

Try the following:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Adds the selected file to the list
    using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog
        {
            Multiselect = false
        })
    {
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            this.listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName));
        }
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Adds all selected files to the list
    using (OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Multiselect = true
    })
    {
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (var fileName in dlg.FileNames)
            {
                this.listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(fileName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: essentially, the very first line in the listbox is always blank, which I would like to remove, that is all.

Comment: @TheEliteNoob Are you using multi-selection or not? You're using both FileName and FileNames... Also shed some light on first questions in my answer...

Comment: okay, sorry, the string file doesn't matter, had it from before, edited it out. fileDialog is instantiated in the winForms, (drag and drop onto the project)